# Can one embed a group scheme into a locally constant one such that the quotient exists

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $S$ be a good enough base scheme (say of finite type over an algebraic closed field) and $G\to S$ be a flat group scheme. I want to ask: can we always find a closed embedding $G\to H$ into another flat group scheme $H$, such that $H$ is constant over S locally in the Zariski topology, and that $H/G$ exists as a scheme?

Comment: New contributor, welcome! I am not sure I understand what you mean by "constant".

Comment: I mean that there exists a Zariski cover $S'\to S$ such that the base change $H\times_S S'$ is isomorphic to $H_0 \times S'$ (for an algebraic group $H_0$ over the base field) as group schemes over $S'$.

Comment: This is certainly false for families of abelian varieties: subvarieties of abelian varieties cannot be deformed. I am not sure about the affine case.